# HTML Decoding a String in SQL Server

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, html-encode

I have a string that I need to html decode the special characters back to normal characters. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The best way do this is in the code that calls the database, not in the database itself.

Comment: Fair enough - the reason I am doing this in SQL Server is because I am using Visual Studio web performance test validation rules. The only way to give this system a value from a database is to bind it to a column (that is, unless I write a manual extension for their web test and override its functionality).

Comment: @John - You could maybe write a CLR function to do this that invokes the `.NET` framework `HTMLDecode` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use REPLACE function or create UDF which decode  the special characters